# "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" Error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a small problem. I want to display a slideshow, but the images are not moving. When I check it in the console I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Can someone please help me?

Here's my javascript code:

```
        var step=1;
 var images = [
"5c.jpg",
"5s.jpg",
"a65.jpg"
```

];

var slideshow = document.getElementById('slideshow');

```
 function slide(){   
    slideshow.src = images[step];
    if(step<3){
        step++;
    }
    else
        step=1;
    setTimeout("slide()",2500); 
 }
```

and my html file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="C:\Users\M.OAN\Desktop\Pics\Slideshow\5c.jpg" alt="images" name="slide" id="slideshow" onload="slide();"/>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have eval there?

Comment: why are you using eval? you don't even need it

Comment: Please, learn to use arrays. Do not use `eval`.

Comment: thanks for the advice but can u tell me why i m getting this error :/

Comment: How do you plan on deploying this slideshow?

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use strings in `setTimeout`s as it's a XSS issue.

Comment: as u can see from the code it's just changing the src of my image file after every 2500 ms , i actually had put this slide function in my body onload but due to some problems i had to remove it from there and had to put it in my image

Comment: I don't know what you think eval is for but it certainly makes zero sense in this context. I suggest looking up its documentation.

Comment: i have edited the code -_-
still no luck

Comment: @user3624126 remove `name="slide"` from your image tag

Comment: that's doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Array with your image paths and then just iterate thru it:

HTML:

```
<img id="slideshow" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" alt="images" name="slide"/>
```

JS:

```
var images = [
    "http://placekitten.com/100/100",
    "http://placekitten.com/100/50",
    "http://placekitten.com/50/100"
];

// get image element
var slideshow = document.getElementById('slideshow');

// in arrays index starts from 0
var step = 0;

setInterval(function(){

    slideshow.src = images[step];

    if( step < images.length-1 ){
        step++;
    } else {
        step = 0;
    }    

}, 2500 );
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FV9Uw/2/)

Btw, I recommend you to use relative paths instead of absolute, because you may have problems when you try deploy your site:

```
"Pics/Slideshow/5c.jpg"
```

instead of

```
"C:/Users/M.OAN/Desktop/Pics/Slideshow/5c.jpg"
```

Comment: @Ejay of course not, I'm just try to solve the first problem, I've added recommendation about source too.

Comment: and i should probably tell u one thing that it was working perfectly when i was calling slide mthod from onload event in body tag but i had to remove it from there for some reasons

Comment: @user3624126 Try fiddle demo that I've inserted above

Comment: it works but i m having the same problem i suffered from when i used onload in body tag, the slideshow starts right at the header but i want the image src to change in the image tag , that's why i specifically called the onload in img tag so the images will be changed there not in header

Comment: @user3624126 I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you try to explain, but if you want to get  specific element in DOM, just use `document.getElementById('elementID')` function.

Comment: I gave my img tag an id and used your fiddle code but it's giving another error as expected "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null " , can someone just give solution to the actual code i posted , these things aren't working , i still don't know wht was wrong with code i have posted in the first place? I've edited my code again.

Comment: @user3624126 This will return null because you are calling the image element before it was loaded. I presume that you put `<script>...</script>` code somewhere in `<head>`, put it just before `</body>` closing tag and it should fix the problem.

Comment: yess @Artem, that did the trick , thanks alot buddy ,it works now :)
you just taught me a new thing today and taught me a lesson too , that i don't know alot about javascript :p , anyways thanks alot everyone for the help :)

Comment: sorry i don't know how to , can u tell me how?

Comment: @user3624126 I've posted a link in previous comment :)

Comment: done :) , btw it says here that i shouldn't have said thank u , it's against the rules , but when someone helps me, not saying thank u is against my rules. So ..... :p

Answer (score 0):

From Fiddling a bit, the source of the original error was that the name of the  tag and the function were the same.

Comment: you should post it in comments .